# cannot integrate d3 into Vue 3 Component

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vuejs3

I've installed the `d3` dependency in the **project directory** like this:

```
npm install d3 --save
```

and I've imported the `d3` module in the `Component` like this:

```
import d3 from "d3";
```

which shows no errors or warnings to me. Unfortunately, calling any method from the `d3` module fails.

For example, I tried to draw [this](https://medium.com/tyrone-tudehope/composing-d3-visualizations-with-vue-js-c65084ccb686) line chart and an error appeared at the very first `select` method from the module.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined.
```

How could this be? Hovering on every single method of the `d3` module in `VS Code` shows me the documentation of the method. So I guess the module can't be undefined.

```
<script>
import d3 from 'd3';
const data = [99, 71, 78, 25, 36, 92];
export default {
  name: 'non-vue-line-chart',
  template: '<div></div>',
  mounted() {
    const svg = d3.select(this.$el) // the error appears on the very first line of the d3-module
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 270)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 10)');
    const x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 430]);
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([210, 0]);
    d3.axisLeft().scale(x);
    d3.axisTop().scale(y);
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, (d, i) => i));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d)]);
    const createPath = d3.line()
      .x((d, i) => x(i))
      .y(d => y(d));
    svg.append('path').attr('d', createPath(data));
  },
};
</script>
```

There must be some integration mismatch, that I can't fix it by myself. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be helpful to know which version of d3 you are using. I'm going to assume it's the latest, which at this time is v6.

d3 v4 still uses `import d3 from 'd3';` way to import, but in v6 (and v5) the use ES modules now and way to do is.

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

This change allows the developer to select which features they need, and the compiler can then tree-shake the dependency and only include features needed.

So you could also do:

```js
import {select, scaleLinear, axisLeft, axisTop, extent, max, line} as d3 from 'd3';
```

and end up with a smaller bundle

---

### Update

The error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.` is telling you that `$el` in `d3.select(this.$el)` is not a Node.
To resolve this, use inside `this.$nextTick(function () {...})`

[docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#mounted)

> #### `mounted`
>
> **Type:** Function
>
> **Details: **
>
> Called after the instance has been mounted, where element, passed to app.mount is replaced by the newly created vm.$el. If the root instance is mounted to an in-document element, vm.$el will also be in-document when mounted is called.
>
> Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted. If you want to wait until the entire view has been rendered, you can use vm.$nextTick inside of mounted:
>
> ```js
> mounted() {
>   this.$nextTick(function () {
>     // Code that will run only after the
>     // entire view has been rendered
>   })
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I have installed the latest d3 version and I went with the first approach `import * as d3 from `d3``, the second one was rejected from the compiler immediately. 
However, I'm still getting an error. This time I get this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.`
Do you maybe recommend me a lower d3 version?

Comment: that's because `this.$el` is null or undefined at the time of mount, you will likely need to defer 'till after $el resolves to a Node.

Comment: thank you so much for your response and sorry for the delay (was 2 days off). This seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5800). I couldn't make it work. I will accept your answer, because I really appreciate your help.